# Android + jmockit: java.lang.VerifyError: mockit/internal/startup/Startup

Tags: java, android, junit, jmockit, jmock

I got an error below when I try to change from Calendar class to a mock class by using jmockit(version1.8).

Doen anyone know how to fix it ? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

---

CalendarMock.java

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import mockit.*;

public final class CalendarMock extends MockUp<Calendar> {
   @Mock
   public static Long getInstance() { return new GregorianCalendar(2000, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).getTimeInMillis(); }
}
```

---

DummyTest.java

```
public void testDummy() throws Exception {
    new CalendarMock();
}
```

---

Error Log

```
java.lang.VerifyError: mockit/internal/startup/Startup
at mockit.MockUp.<clinit>(MockUp.java:85)
at com.hoge.testDummy(DummyTest.java:)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Comment: Are you running the test on the Dalvik VM? JMockit uses the `java.lang.instrument` API which is not available on Dalvik, so it can't work in this environment; you would need to use a JVM.

Comment: @Rogério Thanks! Re Really!? Yes, I'm trying to use JMockit on Android. How can I use mock on the Dalvik VM?

Comment: You would have to use some other mocking tool which can run in the Dalvik VM. JMockit only works with a JVM.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to anwer but it can be useful for other users, I think that if you want to use jmokit you have to use robolectric too that allows you to run the tests on JVM not in Dalvik, or you can change the framework and using mikito for android.

Answer (score 0):

Set `-Xverify` as `none` in JVM arguments as below, This will disable java bytecode verification:

```
 -Xverify\:none
```

Xverify : [Reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.15/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/xverify.html).

If this works, you 'll get the root cause of the issue.